# Primefaces dataTable rowEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces' `p:dataTable` to display an editable table. Is there any way to detect when the `p:rowEditor` icon has been clicked? I need this because i want to disable, when in editing mode, a `p:commandLink` that i've added for row deletion.

And here's the .xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                 paginator="true"
                 paginatorPosition="top"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {PageLinks} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50"
                 rows="10"
                 editable="true"
                 value="#{userController.allUsers}"
                 var="user"
                 > 
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{userController.onEdit}"/>
        <p:column headerText="First Name">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.firstname}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{user.firstname}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        //. . . some other data columns

        <p:column headerText="Options">
            <p:rowEditor/> <br/>
            <p:commandLink id="deleteLink" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"  action="#{userController.deleteUser(user.userId)}"/>
        </p:column>
```

And here the parts of the bean i find relevant:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserController {
    @EJB
    private UserBean userBean;
    @EJB
    private TeamBean teamBean;
    private Integer currentUserId;
    private String newUserUsername;
    private String newUserPassword;
    private User.AccountType newUserAccountType;
    private String newUserFirstName;
    private String newUserLastName;
    private Integer newUserTeamId;

    // ... some create/ update/ delete functions that work

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        try {
            User user = (User) event.getObject();
            System.out.println("Edit: " + user);

            userBean.update(user.getUserId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), 
                User.AccountType.valueOf(user.getAccountType()), user.getFirstname(), user.getLastname(),
                user.getTeam() == null ? null : user.getTeam().getTeamId());
            System.out.println("User " + user.getUserId() + " updated: " + user.getFirstname());
    } catch (InexistentUserException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidUsernameException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InexistentTeamException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (DataBaseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the link? inside the same row or outside the table? Also please send your xhtml and java please

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan Hi! I've added the missing source code (my mistake). The link for the delete action is inside the same row, beside the `p:rowEditor`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The event to detect when the p:rowEditor was clicked is:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{Bean.someListener}" />
```

Comment: it this event how can i get the object for which edit is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

Just use another `<p:cellEditor>` inside your column.

```
<p:column headerText="Options">
  <p:rowEditor/>
  <p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output">
      <p:commandLink id="deleteLink" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"  action="#{userController.deleteUser(user.userId)}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">

    </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

I also recommend you to place deleteLink inside another column.

Comment: It's a great idea for hiding the link, but when i do this the delete action no longer works. It simply doesn't call the bean method.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research event="rowEditInit" is the correct to catch the pencil click of an editable row.

Thanks